$L^2$ property of samples
Assume a continuous, differentiable function $x(t)$ which is uniformly bounded and $L^2$ i.e.
$\int_0^\infty{x^2(s)ds}<\infty$ and its derivative is also uniformly bounded. Do we also have that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^2(k)<\infty$? If not, what extra assumptions are needed to ensure this property?
My analysis: Since $x,\dot{x}\in L^{\infty}$ and $x\in L^2$ one has from Barbalat's lemma that $x(t)\rightarrow 0$ and therefore $x(k)\rightarrow 0$.

This is not true without further assumptions. Let $\phi$ denote the function
$$
\phi(t) = \chi_{(-1/2,+1/2)} ( \cos(2\pi t)+1 )
$$
with support $[-1/2,+1/2]$.
Now define
$$
x(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1/2} \phi(k^{1/2} (t - k)).
$$
Then the supports of these functions $\phi(k (\cdot - k))$ do not overlap, and $x,\dot x$ are in $L^\infty$. In addition,
$$
\int_0^\infty x(t)^2 dt \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} k^{-1} \phi(k^{1/2} (t - k)) ^2dt \\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} k^{-3/2} \phi(s) ^2ds < \infty.
$$
However,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x(k)|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1} = +\infty.
$$

If in addition $x \dot x$ is integrable then the claim is true.
Since
$$
\frac d{dt}  (t-k) x(t)^2 = x(t)^2 + (t-k) x(t) \dot x(t),
$$
we have
$$
\int_k^{k+1} x(t)^2 + (t-k) x(t) \dot x(t) dt = x(k+1)^2-0, 
$$
which allows to estimate
$$
x(k+1)^2 = \int_k^{k+1} x(t)^2 + (t-k) x(t) \dot x(t) dt
\le \int_k^{k+1} x(t)^2 + |x(t)\dot x(t)| dt
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
x(k+1)^2 
\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} x(t)^2 + |x(t)\dot x(t)| dt
\le \|x\|_{L^2}^2 + \|x\dot x\|_{L^1}.
$$

Thank you! I was actually thinking that the claim would be true if $|\dot{x}|\leq c |x|$ (linear growth condition) for some $c>0$. Well, this can be directly obtained from the integrability of $x\dot{x}$ and the L^2 property of $x$.
